# Generate a wave noise map

Tags: graphics, perlin-noise

How can we generate the wave-like texture like this[image: by TheRujiK]

The author(RujiK) says in reply he used the texture generator(http://www.kitfox.com/projects/perlinNoiseMaker/index.html), but no matter how I tweak the parameters, it looks quite different from the original version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make it with that generator alone, but you can use it as a starting point. It looks like the sparseness comes from adjusting the cutoff values - you just take regular noise, and make all pixels below certain gray level black, and all pixels above a different (higher) gray level white.

Some noise generators will allow you to adjust this, but you can also simulate it in an image processing program, like Photoshop - or maybe code it yourself as a shader. For example, start with this:

[image]

Note that I used only 2 levels of noise; your source image doesn't seem to have many levels mixed in. Now apply the Levels filter (left image), or alternatively, the Curves filter (right):

[image]
[image]

Play with the cutoff values until you get something like this:

[image]

Adjust vertical tiling:

[image]

Now you can apply a color ramp to it, to map the grayscale values to a color gradient:

[image]

Obtaining something like this:
[image]

[image]

Again, you can tweak the cutoff parameters to adjust the result to your liking. Here's how it looks with slightly larger cutoffs on both sides:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe RujiK has generated a perlin-noise texture. Then they set a tiling on this texture to be unproportional on X axis/width which stretches it out.

For this effect it doesn't necessary need to have a colour, but I believe colour was added afterwards in some editing software. White - reddish, dark - blueish.

I have used `Groovy` effect to better display the values of white and black. But you would generate a texture without it and make some modifications to make white values whiteish and black values blackish to differentiate more.

[image: Groovy noise smear]

These were my settings

[image: Texture gen settings]

Comment: I thought of scaling as you do, but his version looks more "sparse". I guess it's just because of different parameters. I will wait a bit to see if we have other answers!

Comment: @JiehongJiang you could also try searching for `caustic texture generator`. It seems closer to the desired result, but I haven't been able to find a free version. I am not even sure if generator on top is a free version. There are lots of open source projects that generate this kind of textures, so they might be helpful.